# Not getting viewDidLoad or Appear when switching tabs -- can I use NSNotification?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

When I switch tabs in my tab bar application, one of my views needs to update because the user may have changed a preference that affects it. It is a `UIViewController`'s view, but when the views switch, the `viewDidLoad`/`Appear` methods aren't called. Can this be solved using an `NSNotification` or any other way? Please give example code, especially for `NSNotification`s, as I am new to them.

Comment: Why aren't they getting called? Are you using a `UITabBarController` object or just a `UITabBar`?

Comment: The entire app runs on the UITabBarController but the view I am talking about is a subview of one of the tabs. I just want to know how to make it update when the tabs are switched.

Comment: So it is [tabBarController]->[viewController]->[view]->[yourView](which is controlled by a view controller). Have I got the path right?

Comment: yes, only there is one more view and view controller after the first view controller and view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to peek at `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`. There you can determine how to handle the view change and whether you need to update the view based on the possible preference change.

Answer (score 1):

tabBarController:didSelectViewController: you can implement this method in the appdelegate.
 you will get the sxact root view controller at which yopu clicked . then you can update that view .